# PowerShell List View Threshold Error when trying to storage quota of a document library

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm facing an issue when trying to use PowerShell to get information on document library sizes in site collections with SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

My PowerShell code is as follows:

```
$siteURL = "http://myonpremsharepoint.com/sites/ABC"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
  foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
  {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")  
      {
        $listSize = 0
        foreach ($item in $list.items)
        {
          $listSize += ($item.file).length
        }
      "Web: "+$web.Title+", Library Name: "+$list.Title+", Size: "+[Math]::Round(($listSize/1KB),2)+"KB"    
    }
  }
}
```

The error I receive after running on this on some of my larger document libraries is as follows:

```
The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

At Line: 8 char:22
  foreach ($item in $list.items)
  CategoryInfo                  : NotSpecified: <:> [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

Is there a way to rewrite the above PowerShell query to ignore this limitation without having to specifically change the threshold limit for the given document library?

Thanks